# How do I automatically press the approve button on a cryptocurrency wallet?

Tags: javascript, node.js, cryptography, cryptocurrency

Does anyone know how you can track the appearance of a new dialog box and item on it? I have a crypto-purse for example, I click on the button (any, mint or purchase) -> a dialog box pops up (which refers to the extension, not the browser) -> the script automatically reads it and clicks the button.

[image]

I already tried everything, even tried to change the extension (wallet), so that transactions in it were automatically confirmed, but nothing works. The script simply does not see the new dialog box and items on it, and it is impossible to trace in advance, since it does not appear immediately

I want the js script to automatically look for all new windows and look for an element on them that contains the approve button and click on it

[image]

I tried to change the extension as a whole to have transactions automatically confirmed, but to no avail